# Featured image to the share link in social media such as whatsapp and fb messaging

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, api

For now , i'm using

```
< meta property="og:image" content="<?php print_r( $result->result->profilepicture ); ?>" />
```

but, what should i do to pull the content from the database because right now, the code not working to display the image from the database. The image pull from the database also must linked to the requested ID in URL

For example if the url `https://example/test.php?FB00000001` , the ID is FB00000001 , the featured image must be pulled from the database based on the ID. Can someone help me ? i'm newbie here .

Answer (score 0):

Open Graph property image (og:image) needs an URL of image in content property like

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

Typically in web we don't store images and other binary files directly in database. (Although it's possible using blob type field).

Simple algorithm is upload image file to the server folder, for ex. /server/root/upload with Url http://server.com/upload/...

Then you just save to database the name of uploaded file and build URL:
1) Get name of the file from mysql field.
2) Build URL:

```
$url = "http://server.com/upload/".$filename;
```

3) Ouput Open Graph tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=$url?>" />
```